# How to deal with the NA or NULL value in if statement?

Tags: r

I have a data set `allProductPrice` like following:

```
#data
allProductPrice <- read.table(text="OrderYear  Product   Price
2013       RP110    1790.00000
2014       RP110    1195.08511
2013       RP111    726.77000
2012       EI25     400.15221
2013       EI25     440.89647
2014       EI25     368.97858
2013       FG26     151.09750
2014       FG26     383.09938
2012       RB30     619.70698
2013       RB30     642.82010
2014       RB30     695.00977", header=TRUE)
```

I want to classify the prices to different price levels Price4(1500-2000) Price3(1000-1500),Price2(500-1000),Price1(0-500) and get the table `priceLevel`.

```
Year  Price1 Price2 Price3 Price4
2012  1        1      0      0
2013  3        2      0      1
2014  3        1      1      0
```

My logic: first get all the years and Products, then use nested loop to locate each product's price and then count by years and the price levels. Here is my code:

```
#get the year and product
validYears<-unique(allProductPrice$OrderYear)
AllPRID<-unique(allProductPrice$Product)
AllPRID<-as.character(AllPRID)

#create a new table for Price levels
priceLevel<-data.frame(Year=validYears,Price1=0,Price2=0,Price3=0,Price4=0)

#inital value for UP
UP<-0

#start the loop
for (year in validYears) {
  for(PrId in AllPRID){
      UP<-allProductPrice$Price[allProductPrice$OrderYear==year&allProductPrice$Product==PrId]

    if(is.na(UP)==TRUE&&is.null(UP)==TRUE){
         print("NULL")
  } else if(UP<500){
      priceLevel$Price1[priceLevel$Year==year]<-priceLevel$Price1[priceLevel$Year==year]+1
  }  else if(UP>500&&UP<1000) {
    priceLevel$Price2[priceLevel$Year==year]<-priceLevel$Price2[priceLevel$Year==year]+1
  }  else if(UP>1000&&UP<1500)  {
      priceLevel$Price3[priceLevel$Year==year]<-priceLevel$Price3[priceLevel$Year==year]+1
  }  else {
        priceLevel$Price4[priceLevel$Year==year]<-priceLevel$Price4[priceLevel$Year==year]+1
  } 
  }}
```

I always get error message such as

```
Error in if (UP < 500) { : argument is of length zero
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Try `table(df$OrderYear,findInterval(df$Price,c(500,1000,1500,2000)))` to get close to what you want.

Comment: @nicola post as an answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `cut()` function:

```
#using cut create groups
allProductPrice$Group <- 
  paste0("Price",
         cut(allProductPrice$Price, 
             c(0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000),
             c(1, 2, 3, 4)))

#result - use table then convert to a data.frame
as.data.frame.matrix(
  table(allProductPrice$OrderYear, allProductPrice$Group))


#      Price1 Price2 Price3 Price4
# 2012      1      1      0      0
# 2013      2      2      0      1
# 2014      2      1      1      0
```

Comment: Thank you!!I haven't thought to create a new column to find out the price level in the original table. It's really helpful to think differently and make the solution simpler! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
#create a new column with the price categories
df$PriceCat<-paste0("Price",findInterval(df$Price,c(0,500,1000,1500,2000)))
table(df[,c("OrderYear","PriceCat")])
#         PriceCat
#OrderYear Price1 Price2 Price3 Price4 
#     2012      1      1      0      0
#     2013      2      2      0      1
#     2014      2      1      1      0
```

Comment: Thank you for constructive suggestion! Really helpful! Now I learn `findInerval` and `cut` to create thresholds.